# Numpy automatically converting array of strings to array of numbers

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, types

I have an array of strings that is composed of number-like strings such as `010`. I am trying to build a 2D numpy array by creating an empty numpy array, and then filling in the rows with my array of strings. However, it seems like whenever I assign a row in the numpy array, it converts the number-like strings into numbers. The main issue with this behavior is that I am losing leading zeroes from my strings.

I wrote a simple example to show what is happening:

```
import numpy as np

num_rows = 5
arr = ["010", "011", "111", "100", "001"]
np_arr = np.empty((num_rows, len(arr)), dtype=str)

for i in range(len(np_arr)):
    np_arr[i] = arr

print(np_arr)
```

The resulting output is:

```
[['0' '0' '1' '1' '0']
 ['0' '0' '1' '1' '0']
 ['0' '0' '1' '1' '0']
 ['0' '0' '1' '1' '0']
 ['0' '0' '1' '1' '0']]
```

vs. the expected output:

```
[['010' '011' '111' '100' '001']
 ['010' '011' '111' '100' '001']
 ['010' '011' '111' '100' '001']
 ['010' '011' '111' '100' '001']
 ['010' '011' '111' '100' '001']]
```

I do not understand this behavior and am hoping to find a solution to my problem and understand if this type conversion is being done by numpy or by Python. I have tried quite a few variations to this small example but have not found a working solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the type of the array: you need to set an [array-protocol type string](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.dtypes.html), like `<U3`: if you change `dtype=str` to `dtype='<U3'` it will work.

Comment: This is a good generalized solution that fixed my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution:

```
num_rows = 5
arr = ["010", "011", "111", "100", "001"]

# Turn your array into a numpy array with dtype string.
n = np.array(arr, dtype=str)

# Repeat the row as many times as needed.
n = np.tile(n, num_rows).reshape(num_rows, len(n))
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

A note for the future is that in most cases, you can replace `for` loops with NumPy functions, which tend to be faster due to vectorisation.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there a variation to this answer that works with more than 1 array? In the example I just repeated the same array `num_rows` times, but in practice I will have many different arrays I want to fill the numpy array with. I tried converting each array I have to a numpy array using `np.array(...)` like you suggested, but if I don't use that `tile` function then I get the same results as in the question.

Comment: Could you post some of your other arrays please, so I know what format they're in?

Comment: If the arrays are all the same shape, have a look at numpy.stack

Comment: @AJH they are all identical to the one I have in my example, just with different values. @RuthC `numpy.stack` looks like a nice way to solve this problem too!